# jquery from index to loaded div file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

Ok so the title is a little odd but wasn't sure how to describe problem in 1 line (feel free to update it) so I'll explain the best I can.

I load content from a file foobar.php into a div `#foobar` in index.php like so:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('id'),
          cls = $(this).attr('class'),
         dstr = 'id='+id;

        if(cls=='bar'){

          $.ajax({
             type:'GET',
              url:'foobar.php',
             data:dstr,
            cache:false,
          success:function(a){
       // this is where it calls for the content of foobar.php 
            $('#foobar').html(a);
      }}
     )
    }
  return false;
});
```

in foobar.php it queries database and shows the results depending on unique id which works fine, but it also has a form which I'm trying to use with [jquery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Now if I add the script links in foobar.php it works great:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.min.js"></script>
```

**but** these jquery files are are loaded in index.php so am wanting if possible to get jquery.form to work using the already loaded jquery files from index.php.

I know it doesn't currently work as it has something to do with the fact the content of foobar.php is being loaded into/via a dom and so as the lines above are not present in foobar.php it can't call them?!

Comment: Yes, it is possible and yes it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call this (with your form selector instead of "#myForm") after you have loaded the page within the success function.

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
});
```